# Eclipse "Copy Qualified Name" function in Visual Studio?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio

In Eclipse (for Java) I got used to the function *Copy Qualified Name* available in the context menu of the code window, which copied the fully qualified name of a type or method under the cursor into the clipboard. After switching to Visual Studio I am unable find an equivalent of this useful tool.

Is there a *Copy Qualified Name* function somewhere in Visual Studio? (Or is it in some plugin?)

If **not**, is there at least a good workaround which does not require a successful build and launch of my application nor forces me to manually re-type a qualified name visible somewhere on the screen?

I'm currently using VS 2012 Pro and need this in a Visual Basic project.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure if this will be convenient enough for you, but you can choose `View` menu item and open the `Class view` window (`Ctrl+W,C` or `Ctrl+Shift+C` short cut - probably depends on the settings). There you can select a class or a method and pressing `Ctrl+C` (or choosing `Copy` from context menu) gives you the fully qualified name in the clipboard.

Comment: I'm using `VS10x Code Map` plugin for overview of currently open code. This might partially assist in need of tracking and insight functionality. For C# it also highlights methods currently in editor viewport.

Comment: Note: you can't just search the class view for the thing you want to find, so dig a little more and maybe search will work

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019, when your cursor is on the name of a class, field or property, and you open the Class View with Ctrl+Shift+C, the corresponding item in the Class View will usually become selected. You can then follow up with Ctrl+C to copy the qualified name to clipboard.

Answer (score 20):

The latest version of ReSharper includes the [`ReSharper_CopyFqn`](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Copying_Symbol_Information_to_Clipboard.html) command, which will copy a fully-qualified type name to the clipboard for the currently selected symbol.

Comment: This is in the menu `ReSharper -> Edit -> Copy Fully-qualified name to Clipboard`

Comment: @mattalxndr – I don't think so, because I asked primarily about the Visual Studio and ReSharper is a different piece of software, out of reach for many developers.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+C

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this still needed, but I just published extension to copy qualified name in Visual studio, you can find it here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f15022a5-aec4-44e7-a51d-6c24df3b55e0

Comment: Thank you! Just dropped some stars on the marketplace for you.

Answer (score 4):

#### My own answer to my question:

Quite a long time I was using the command in answer I got for this question. Too bad that the Visual Studio command given in accepted answer is:

- relatively hard to reach - lack of **Class View** pane synchronization requires further navigation
- not included in list of commands in the Visual Studio - no keyboard shortcut can be attached to the command

Few weeks ago I asked author of [Supercharger](http://supercharger.tools) Visual Studio plugin to add the functionality in there and he found it useful and added it. This is now quite comfortable way to get the fully qualified name. The view is similar to original **Class View** pane, but is synchronized with current location in code, so finding desired member is painless, compared to procedure in original Class View pane. Here's an image of open context menu on sample `SortedLines` property:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ReSharper Ultimate 2017.3.2, where you can select "ReSharper" > "Edit" > "Copy XML-Doc ID to Clipboard":
[image]

The copied string looks like this:

```
M:EnEffCoWeb.Chart.ColorPickerTemplate.InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update from 2022: In ReSharper, `ReSharper_CopyFqn` is now "[Copy code reference to clipboard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Copying_Symbol_Information_to_Clipboard.html)"

The shortcut is `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+C`:

> When you need to log or share the context of the current location,
> such as the name of the symbol under the caret or its
> XML-documentation ID, the path to the file or the VCS path, you can
> press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+C and copy the desired reference from a popup