# Visual studio copy type name to clipboard

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When you hover on a variable in Visual Studio 2017, the type name is displayed.

[image: Hovering over variable in Visual Studio 2017, displaying type name]

How can one copy the string `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IGrouping<FileType, IFileInfo>>` into the clipboard?

ReSharper's Copy FQN to Clipboard function copies `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` to the clipboard, which is certainly in the right direction but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In debugging you could type files.GetType().Name (or .FullName) in the VS Immediate window or elsewhere (quick watch, etc).

While coding, some VS extensions like resharper allow you to replace the "var" keyword by actual type name in a single click but this is maybe not what you want.

Comment: Actually, I honestly can't believe I didn't think of replacing `var` with ReSharper then changing it back after I copied it. Yay for the internet! My use case is just plopping the type name somewhere else in (several) other code files, so the debugger idea probably takes longer than just typing it out.

Comment: You're welcome ! I think you could also like this SO question as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475242/eclipse-copy-qualified-name-function-in-visual-studio